# Use Firebase authentication in aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-authentication, amazon-cognito

I am using firebase auth as a authentication service in my app.
and using dynamoDB,S3 and other AWS services.Now the problem is that I want to restrict file uploadation to s3 from only firebase authenticated user..How to achieve this?
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the user is logged in with firebase auth https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Then if logged in you can allows s3 uploads.

Without seeing the code to your app you will have to design the solution yourself using these basic guidelines.

Comment: means it will be done at client side not server side?

Comment: yes the client needs to login and get a token back, which can used to verify they are logged in to firebase.